# I am trying to enter data into the database using firebase and android but data is not getting fed into the database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

**MainActivity file**

attaching my MainActivity ..can't find where is the bug the app is building up successfully but data is not showing up in the database, Also for the convenience permission to the database has been granted to all users, Later can be changed...Please help

attaching my MainActivity ..can't find where is the bug the app is building up successfully but data is not showing up in the database, Also for the convenience permission to the database has been granted to all users, Later can be changed...Please help

```
    package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.InputFilter;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

        public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
        public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;

        private ListView mMessageListView;
        private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
        private EditText mMessageEditText;
        private Button mSendButton;

        private String mUsername;

        private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;//firebase database object.It is an entry point to access the database
        private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;//is a class that references the specific part of the database.it will be referencring the messaging portion of the database


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

           // mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();//main access for our database
            //mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");//using this we are getting the acess to messages section of the database
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");

            // Initialize references to views
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
            mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
            mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
            mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

            // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
            List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
            mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
            mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

            // Initialize progress bar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

            // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
            mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
                }
            });

            mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Send messages on click
                    //FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                    //mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    //above statement is used to send the data to the cloud

                    FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                    mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);


                    // Clear input box
                    mMessageEditText.setText("");
                }
            });
            // Enable Send button when there's text to send
            mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                        mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                }
            });
            mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

            // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
            mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO: Send messages on click

                    // Clear input box
                    mMessageEditText.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Generally the debugging will reveal where your application is breaking.

Comment: did it says permission denied..but by default, i have given read and write permission to all users

Comment: Sounds to me like it is a database user issue and not your code. I would try to verify the user that your application is using and see if it has permission to access the DB.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth==null",
    ".write": "auth==null"
  }
}

Comment: The code seems very similar to Google Firebase Chat tutorial app. Did you create the project in firebase console and use the JSON generated by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have setup the required dependencies, follow the most up to date guide at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Or in Android Studio, you can just import the app with Tool -> Firebase -> [ex. Realtime Database] [[image: import app using android studio's built-in tool]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FEPN.png)

With the database rule:

```
{ "rules": { ".read": "auth==null", ".write": "auth==null" } }
```

doesn't grant all user, this rule just grant user read/write who are not authenticated.

Solution: set the read/write rules to true for, testing only (until you use Firebase Authentication)

```
{ ".read" : "true", ".write": "true"}
```

Comment: are there any setting that needs to be imported to the android studio or any dependencies needed to be added

Comment: Yes there are settings and dependencies required, did you go through with the setup?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup